# How to Center Jpanel in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

There is a class which extends `JFrame`. then Further `JFrame` have `JPanel` named contentPane and this Jpanel contains 2 more jpanel. as Tree shown in picture.

[image: Here is the Image]

I Want to Center that **contentPane** in `JFrame` so that on changing size of `JFrame` `JPanel` (contentPane) will remain in center. I have tried with different `Layouts` but did not come up with right one. is there any way ?
Full page picture is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38HHV.png)

Code is this.

```
public class Purchases extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Purchases frame = new Purchases();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }); 
    }


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 513, 438);


        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);



        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 477, 193);
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 214, 477, 174);
        contentPane.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

}
```

**This code is Eclipse automatically generated. I did not find where the contentPane is added in JFrame.**

Comment: do you just want to center the panel, so that on resize ( jframe gets bigger) there is a empty border on all sides ? this seems a bit unnatural to me

Comment: if there is empty borders i will increase the size of JPanel. porblem is to center. size i will handle

Comment: Add the panel as a single component to a `GridBagLayout` that will center it.   E.G. as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9090772/418556).

Comment: Personally, set the frame's content pane to `GridBagLayout`, then wrap your existing content to another `JPanel` and then add this to the frame.

Comment: @Andrew that code have 4 different things i need only one. I am Trying let me check if it helps

Comment: @MadProgrammer can i get a sample. or u can explain it more ?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058565/how-to-center-jpanel-when-jframe-is-resized-or-maximized/21058902#21058902)

Comment: @MadProgrammer form that code i got, I have to add one more panel ? I am right? let me try it.

Comment: That certainly would be my guess...

Answer (score 3):

Set the frame's layout to `GridBagLayout`.  Wrap your existing content in another `JPanel`, add this panel to the frame

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058565/how-to-center-jpanel-when-jframe-is-resized-or-maximized/21058902#21058902)

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

You really should avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 1):

I have made a sample for you. Modify it as per your need. Just want to show you what you want, is working.

```
    TestClass()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 513, 438);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton b1 = new JButton("hello");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        //panel.setBounds(10, 10, 477, 193);
        panel.add(b1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        //panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("why");
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        //panel_1.setBounds(10, 214, 477, 174);
        panel_1.add(b2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        //panel_1.setLayout(null);

        this.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
    }
```

Hope this will help. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should set the maximum size of the element & set it to align center:

```
setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
```

As explained here:
[How can I properly center a JPanel ( FIXED SIZE ) inside a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223530/how-can-i-properly-center-a-jpanel-fixed-size-inside-a-jframe)

Comment: let me see if it helps

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: And if you remove the MaximumSize(), it doesn't center it?

Comment: its already not in center so what to do with maximumSize. actually that code is IDE generated. if i could understand that i have done it :@